# Show Superscript char in tooltip of a html control?

Tags: html

I want to know, it's possible to show superscript character in the tool tip of html control
for ex.

```
$(tblth).attr("title","name <sup>a</sup>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's not HTML (it's natively rendered and depends on the OS), no you can't do that.

The usual solution is to do your own tooltip (or use one of the numerous libraries). The good news is that's easy.